# Cordova Write To WWW Directory (iOS)

Tags: ios, image, cordova, file-io

I am trying to write a file to a directory within the `WWW` directory of my Cordova app.

Here is the situation:

1. My program saves an image to the temporary directory
2. I want the program to move the image from the temporary directory to the `WWW` directory, so that the file does not get deleted every time the app is initialized.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not possible. The WWW is sandboxed and therefore, you can't write anything inside of this folder. If you want to save a file you need to use the DOCUMENTS path and rely on the Cordova file plugin (PERSISTENT is the keyword)

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

You can also check the folder permissions here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#ios-file-system-layout

As you can see, www is read-only (not r/w)