# Cordova saving image downloads to www folder

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm writing an app which house over 1000 small images in the www/images folder in my cordova app (am using Intel XDK for the build). The app needs to check for updates and download images that the user doesn't have, along with other content. I want the new images to be saved to the same folder as the existing images (www/images) and can't find anywhere how to do this. All I find is articles about Cordova saving camera images to gallery/camera roll etc.

The content will be run through and "injected" script which will save it to localStorage. I'm just struggling with the images.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this. The www folder is part of the app bundle, and is sandboxed to protect it from, well, writing. That's the same answer someone else got here: [Cordova Write To WWW Directory (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370206/cordova-write-to-www-directory-ios).

You have to use the File API to write to one of the writable file areas available to the app. You can find some examples of how to do that here: https://github.com/johnwargo/apache-cordova-api-cookbook-code/tree/master/chapter10-file.

Some details from the book:

> The Cordova File API provides an application with the methods it needs
>   to interact with the device’s local directory structure. The API
>   exposes methods an application can use to browse the file system,
>   read, write, copy, move and remove files. An application cannot access
>   just any part of the file system, only the temporary and persistent
>   file storage locations (described below) on a mobile device.
>
> Cordova’s implementation of the File API is based in part on the W3C
>   File API: Directories and System specification
>   (www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api). Not all of the capabilities of the
>   W3C specification have been implemented, but the API provides the
>   essential capabilities most mobile developers will need.
>
> An application would use this API to read and write files on the
>   device file system. An application might use one of the many available
>   storage options for web application to store application data, but
>   developers can also use the file system to persist application
>   settings or application data using the file system, writing text files
>   (in XML or JSON format for example) as needed while the application
>   runs. Additionally, remember that the Camera (Chapter 3) and Capture
>   (Chapter 4) APIs write their files to the file system, applications
>   use the File API to manipulate those files as needed.
>
> Most smartphone provide applications with two different types of file
>   storage space. To store temporary files, the device exposes a
>   temporary storage location. For content and data that is integral to
>   the application’s operation and must remain available after the
>   application is closed and restarted the application should use
>   persistent storage.
>
> In general, an application might use temporary storage for transient
>   data, data that’s written to the file system as part of a memory
>   management strategy or as swap space when analyzing or manipulating a
>   large amount of data. With temporary storage, the application can read
>   from and write to the storage area with impunity, creating and
>   deleting files as needed within the available storage limitations of
>   the device. The device OS may automatically empty temporary storage
>   when the application closes or the device reboots – freeing up storage
>   space for other applications.
>
> Persistent storage on the other hand is more stable; the device OS
>   protects it during reboots and when the application closes. An
>   application’s persistent storage will be emptied by the OS only when
>   the application is uninstalled from the device.
>
> In the sample application, the application’s UI exposes buttons that
>   are used to interact with the different file system types as shown in
>   Figure 10.1. As you can see from the figure, I used jQuery Mobile for
>   the application’s UI in order to simplify the code and let jQuery
>   Mobile deal with rendering file lists, transitioning between pages and
>   so on.